# NestJS => PostgresQL: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN postgres at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup

Tags: postgresql, nestjs

I've been developing a NestJS-GraphQL app connecting to my local Postgres database.
Everything had been working fine until Ubuntu 20.04 reinstallation.

After cloning a repo with the project, installing Postgres, and building the application with **yarn start:dev** I can see this strange error:

```
[Nest] 21577  - 02/05/2022, 2:51:10 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN postgres
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26)
```

Postgres is running:

```
hleb@hleb:~$ psql artwine postgres
psql (14.1 (Ubuntu 14.1-2.pgdg20.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

artwine=#
```

/etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                trust

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

/etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_ident.conf

```
# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
user1           hleb                    postgres
```

.env

```
DB_TYPE=postgres
DB_HOST=postgres
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USERNAME=hleb
DB_NAME=artwine
DB_PASSWORD=Mypassword
```

Looking forward to the community help as I have no idea what could go wrong.
**Tried**: node_modules reinstall, Postgres reinstall, dist folder recreation.

Remark:
After building a repo with yarn start:dev I ran the application in docker container using docker-compose. Everything worked fine with no errors. Maybe it will be useful for the investigation.
Thanks for your time, do appreciate it.

Comment: How are you running your server and the database? If it's being ran locally or only the database is being ran through docker-compose with the correct ports exposed, your `DB_HOST` should probbaly be `localhost`

Comment: Oh, yes, exactly! Thank you for your help, works as expected.

Answer (score 6):

DB_HOST=localhost **instead of** DB_HOST=postgres

Comment: Or database service name in docker compose

Answer (score 1):

When running the application completely via `docker-compose` using `DB_HOST=postgres` is fine, as docker-compose will create a DNS resolution between services using the service name as the host. However, with the server running locally, and the database running through `docker-compose` you need to use the value `localhost` for the `DB_HOST`

Comment: Could you please direct me where could I learn the next thing:
So, I'm running my Postgres locally on localhost filling it with data.
Then I want to run the whole app in a docker container, but a new empty database will be created and I expect to lose my data. How to connect existing DB data to a docker container?
(I'm a docker beginner :) )

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. After updating the Postgresql config with no success, it ended up being a "#" in the password of my user.

https://github.com/pantsel/konga/issues/510